# How to generate debug information with Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, command-line, makefile, debug-symbols

I have a C project that can be built in the command line (Linux Mint) which generates 
debug information. I can use GDB to debug it in the command line interface, which I find very tedious.

I have used: **`sudo make DEBUG=1`** in the command line.

I need to debug the same project in Eclipse (GALILEO). I can build it in Eclipse, but no debug information is generated, and I can't debug the code (with the error "No Debugging Information available"). Also can't place any break point in the code.

**I have used `gcc -g` as the compiler invocation command (`compiler > -O2 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0`)
and make `DEBUG=1` in custom build command, with the
linker as "gcc"**

Can anyone tell me how to set up the project so that the debug information is generated just like when it was built in the command line.

---

------------------BUILD OUTPUT------------------------------------------------------------

Build of configuration Default for project yuma ******

make DEBUG=1 STATIC=1 all 
for dir in  libtecla netconf libtoaster; do\
      cd $dir && make && cd ..;\
        done
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/shuser/workspace2/yuma/libtecla'
make[2]: Entering directory`/home/shuser/workspace2/yuma/libtecla'
mkdir normal_obj
cp ./keytab.h normal_obj/keytab.h
gcc -c -O  -DPACKAGE_NAME="" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME="" -DPACKAGE_VERSION="" -DPACKAGE_STRING="" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT="" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_SELECT_H=1 -DHAVE_SELECT=1 -DHAVE_SYSV_PTY=1  -D_SVID_SOURCE -D_BSD_SOURCE  -fpic -o normal_obj/getline.o ./getline.c

[...]

gcc -DLINUX=1 -DGCC=1 -DDEBUG -DHAS_FLOAT=1 -Wall -Wno-long-long -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wswitch-default -Wunused-parameter -Wextra -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-qual -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wpacked -Winvalid-pch -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -std=gnu99  -fPIC -ggdb3   \
         -I. -I../agt -I../mgr -I../ncx -I../platform -I../ydump -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2/libxml   -c -o ../../target/mgr/mgr.o mgr.c 
gcc -DLINUX=1 -DGCC=1 -DDEBUG -DHAS_FLOAT=1 -Wall -Wno-long-long -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wswitch-default -Wunused-parameter -Wextra -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-qual -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wpacked -Winvalid-pch -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -std=gnu99  -fPIC -ggdb3   \
         -I. -I../agt -I../mgr -I../ncx -I../platform -I../ydump -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2/libxml   -c -o ../../target/mgr/mgr_cap.o mgr_cap.c

[...]

gcc -ggdb3 -DDEBUG=1 -DLINUX=1 -DGCC=1 -DHAS_FLOAT=1 -Wall -Wno-long-long -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wswitch-default -Wunused-parameter -Wextra -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wpacked -Winvalid-pch -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -std=gnu99  -fPIC   \
        -I. -I../../netconf/src/platform -I../../netconf/src/ncx -I../../netconf/src/agt -I/usr/include/yuma/platform -I/usr/include/yuma/ncx -I/usr/include/yuma/agt  -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2/libxml   -c -o ../bin/toaster.o toaster.c

---

----------------------DEBUG CONSOLE---------------------------

**No source available for "main() "**

[...]
.gdbinit: No such file or directory.
Reading symbols from /home/shuser/yuma-2.2-2/netconf/target/bin/netconfd...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
1-gdb-set confirm off
1^done
(gdb) 
2-gdb-set width 0
2^done

[...]

=library-loaded,id="/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6",target-name="/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6",host-name="/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
~"Stopped due to shared library event\n"
Stopped due to shared library event
*stopped,thread-id="1",stopped-threads="all",core="0"
22 info sharedlibrary
(gdb)

---

Comment: Can you post some output from the compiler output window? is it a large project? if so maybe just post a couple of the gcc commands that it outputs and the final link command

Comment: @ThePosey: I have added the compiler and debugger outputs